# Faceted panel: lines for each group within group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a faceted panel that I create like this:

```
totalplot <- ggplot(mtcars, 
                    aes(x=mpg,y=hp,color=gear)) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("hp vs mpg") +
  xlab("mpg") + ylab("hp") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold",
                                  size = 20)) +
  theme(text = element_text(size=15))

totalplot + facet_grid(gear ~ .,scales="free_y") # create faceted panel
```

[image]

But for each panel I would like to have two lines, one for `mtcars$vs==1` and another for `mtcars$vs==0`.

I have tried using `aes(x=mpg,y=hp,color=gear,interaction=(gear,vs))`, but it just gives me weird graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this through using the `group` aesthetic in `geom_line()`, or for better readability, mapping it directly to `linetype` (as a factor):

```
library(ggplot2)
totalplot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=hp, color=as.factor(gear))) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=as.factor(vs))) +
  ggtitle("hp vs mpg") +
  xlab("mpg") + ylab("hp") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold",
                                  size = 20)) +
  theme(text = element_text(size=15))

totalplot + facet_grid(gear ~ .,scales="free_y") # create faceted panel
```

`mtcars` doesn't give you the best example though, because not every level of `gear` has both levels of `vs`. Here is a similar example using `diamonds`, which just has more data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df <- select(diamonds, carat, clarity, cut, price) %>%
  filter(clarity==c("SI2", "VS2", "VVS2")) %>%
  filter(cut==c("Fair", "Ideal"))

totalplot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=carat, y=price, colour=as.factor(clarity))) +
  geom_line(aes(group=cut, linetype=cut)) +
  ggtitle("hp vs mpg") +
  xlab("mpg") + ylab("hp") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold",
                                  size = 20)) +
  theme(text = element_text(size=15)) +
  labs(colour="Clarity", linetype="Cut") +
  facet_grid(clarity ~ .,scales="free_y") # create faceted panel
totalplot
```

[image]

Comment: Very well explained, thank you! Could you please tell me how I change the name of "as.factor(clarity)" in the right margin, so it looks nicer? Also, what is the difference between using a group and linetype in aes within geom_line() ? I'm struggling with understanding ggplot2 on a deeper level. I, for example, only thought one used AES within ggplot(), and not within geom_line()...

Comment: `aes()` is helpful for defining different aesthetic elements within each layer in the plot - for example, defining different `linetypes` in one layer, and different `colours` for points in another layer. Using `group` will group the data, and plot the groups individually using whatever `geom` you've specified, with the same aesthetic pieces. Using `linetype` or `colour` with `as.factor()` does the same thing but changes the way the groups are plotted correspondingly. See edits in the code to change legend titles.

Comment: amazing! Thank you so much! That made my day